# How are these two boolean expressions same?

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

How does `AB(1+C'D)` simplify into `AB` in boolean algebra? I cannot compare their truth tables since literal number of these two expressions is not same. So can anyone explain this to me?

P.S: I found this in solution of a problem of Digital Logic book by Morris Mano and Micheal Ciletti. But since it is a brief solution of a problem, there are no explanations given.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, $1+X$ for any $X$ is equal to $1$, whereas $X1 = X$ for any $X$ as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Boolean algebra, 1 represents True and + represents OR.

True OR anything = True.

1 + anything = 1.

1 + C'D = 1.

AB (1 + C'D) = AB.

Comment: And then 1 and anything = anything....so, AB(1+C'D)=AB
...
Got it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So you have `AB(1+C'D)=AB`
`1+C'D` is equal to 1.
We can make a truth table for `1+C'D`
`C|D|C'D|1+C'D`
`1|1|0*1=0|1+0=1`
`1|0|0*0=0|1+0=1`
`0|1|1*1=1|1+1=0`
`0|0|1*0=0|1+0=1`
So it seems as we have an issue. If `C=F` and `D=T` this statement is not true. So, we can say that this isn't a tautology by counterexample.

Comment: Since when does 1+1 = 0?

Comment: In boolean algebra all addition is modulus 2. Boolean algebra can be also defined as $( \mathbb{Z}_2,+_2) $

Comment: @EliSadoff - I think you are confusing a Boolean *ring* with a Boolean algebra.

Comment: The notation with boolean algebra is also not consistent. When I learned boolean algebra `+` was the XOR operator whereas `^` was the and operator and `V` was the or operator

Comment: + means OR (not XOR). 1 + 1 means True OR True which = True.

Comment: Oh sorry. Well my answer makes no sense now because I used notation incorrectly. :(